# SLI Will Not Enable - Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, nvidia-graphics-card, sli

I am trying to get SLI to switch on with windows 8.1. It is a brand new build and I have two identical EVGA 770's on an MSI Z77A-GD65 board. I have a 1000W PSU and Windows can see the two cards just fine.

When I go to select "Maximum 3D Performance" and hit apply, it flashes black, and then shows a GPU holographic looking Chip, Flashes a few more times and then comes back to the desktop and the NVIDIA Control Panel, and SLI is Disabled still.

I have updated the NVIDIA drivers, but not the BIOS, because I have fastboot enabled and I can't get the keyboard to take me there. I think I have to go so far as to reset the CMOS (but that is a different issue).

How do I get the SLI enable to stick? Could it be a MOBO problem? Thanks!

Comment: I recommend upgrading your bios. That could have something to do with the problem you are experiencing. The general rule of thumb with bios updates is: If it's not broken, then don't update it. However, in your case, it's broken, so an update wouldn't be out of the question. If that doesn't work try stress testing each card individually just to make sure it isn't a problem with the cards. Also, you have the SLI bridge connecting the cards right? People forget that now and then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIOS update to 10.11 and then setting the boot options to Windows Boot Manager did the trick.